# How to show rich text in the QCombobox.lineEdit()? or how to replace the lineedit in qcombobox with textedit?

Tags: pyqt, qtextedit, qcombobox

i have this working example

[image: Combobox with multiple checkboxes]

now i want to be able to edit the QLineEdit and highlight items that are not in the dropdown listview,(eg. red background color) , and add auto complete feature. from my understanding, the only viable way is making a custom widget, with a QTextEdit and a listView ( since qlineedit can't display html ?)

edit: eg I have India,China in the lineEdit, but i only want China's bg color to be red since it's not in the dropdown items list

is there an easier way other than this? thanks !

the code is here: http://pastebin.com/WGrj3ud5
and here : http://www.barishcb.com/?p=426

Answer (score 0):

- For the auto-completion, you need to add a [`QCompleter`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qcompleter.html#details) to your QlineEdit
- For the red background, you can dynamically change the style sheet of the QLineEdit:

  ```
  # in case of item not in the dropdown listview:
  self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
  # otherwise:
  self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("")
  ```

Comment: thanks for the instant reply ! but how can i set bg color for only part of the text ? eg. I have India,China in the lineEdit, but i only want China's bg color to be red since it's not in the dropdown items list.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the background of only a part of the text of a QLineEdit.

Comment: That means i have no choice but to create a custom widget or composite widget (using QTextEdit and QListView ) ?

Comment: I'm afraid so, yep :/